# ¿Cómo crear un arreglo para recorrer los resultados de una consulta?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php5, phpexcel

El pequeño código *PHP* de abajo me arroja el resultado de una consulta en la columna `A,B,Q` en *Excel*. El problema ahora es que necesito hacer un arreglo o ciclo en el que se recorra de acuerdo a la columna en la que se encuentre para llenar las demás columnas de la `C:P`. Claro, haciendo uso de otra consulta, no la misma a la primera.

```
$i = 5;
while ($fila = $total->fetch_array()) {
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A'.$i,  $fila['gasto'])
        ->setCellValue('B'.$i,  $fila['lunes'])

        ->setCellValue('Q'.$i, utf8_encode($fila['factura']));
        $i++;
}
```

Comment: puedes hacerlos con un foreach **foreach($filas as $fila){}**

Answer (score 0):

Es dificil sin saber como vas a conseguir los datos para las otras columnas, pero yo haria dos arreglos y asi poblaria las otras celdas, algo asi:

```
$i = 5;
$columnas = ['C', 'D', 'E', ... , 'P'];
$campos = ['martes', 'miercoles', ... ]; // Ese arreglo contiene todas las columnas que vas a usar
    while ($fila = $total->fetch_array()) {
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A'.$i,  $fila['gasto'])
                ->setCellValue('B'.$i,  $fila['lunes'])

                ->setCellValue('Q'.$i, utf8_encode($fila['factura']));
                $fila2 = // Aqui consigues los datos a rellenar
                for ($j = 0; $j < 14; $j++) {
                    $objPHPExcel->setCellValue($columnas[$j].$i, $fila2[$campos[$j]]);
                }
                $i++;   
    }
```

Comment: ok, lo que pasa es que si manejo un arreglo para los títulos de las columnas y posteriormente con una consulta obtengo el llenado de la columna A,B,P, y yo lo que quiero es como relacionar las consultas dentro del while.

Comment: Cual es la consulta que quieres hacer dentro del while?

Comment: Creo no me explique mi consulta es la siguiente y me llena las 3 columnas antes mencionadas                                                                               
 select f.numero, ifnull(b.gasto,0) as enero, concat('05-','01-',f.numero, '-1')factura from uno f 
  LEFT JOIN dos b ON concat('05-','01-',f.partida, '-1')=b.Cuenta where f.numero like'1%'group by f.numero

Comment: Ok, esa es tu consulta para llenar las columnas A,B y P, pero que consulta vas a usar para llenar las otras 14 columnas?

Comment: Bueno pues es la misma consulta en cada Columna solo que ahora van a provenir de otras tablas, tablas que por el momento no se encuntran ya que estas se van generando semanalmente y se tienen que ir actualizando los reportes por semana y asi es como se van a tener que ir cambiando los datos en las columnas,lo que yo quiero es hacer algo como un ciclo que me diga esta consulta llena la columna B y la C no esta su consulta entones llenar sus campos con ceros y asi sucesivamente para cada columna no se si ya me explique.

Comment: A ver si mas o menos te entendi.  Lo que podrias hacer es un array asociativo con el nombre de las tablas apuntado a las columnas que estas deben de llenar.  Luego en un ciclo, puedes hacer una consulta para verificar que cada tabla existe.  Si existe, la consultas y rellenas las columnas respectivas.  Si no existe, llenas las columnas con ceros.

Comment: Bueno me podrias dar un pequeño ejemplo de como seria

Comment: ok genere algo similar a lo que tenia en un principio y con unos cambios pero no me arroja datos ni nada solo en el archivo excel del reporte me dice que el archivo esta dañado. Podria decirme alguien en que me equivoque,  Arreglo es un arreglo que se definió. y arreglo2 es una consulta que pase a arreglo pero no se si realice el nombramiento correcto de la consulta al arreglo.
o tendría que pasar la consulta a un fetch_array primero para manejarla también como arreglo?

$result = mysql_query("show FULL TABLES FROM base'");
$arreglo2 = $conexion->query($result);

Comment: foreach ($arreglo as $item ) {
    if (in_array($item, $arreglo2)){
 
 $i=5;
while ($fila = $consulta->fetch_array()) {
   $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
     ->setCellValue('A'.$i,  $fila['campo'])
     ->setCellValue('B'.$i,  $fila['campo2'])
 
              ->setCellValue('C'.$i, utf8_encode($fila['campo3']));
     $i++;
  }
 
    }
 
 else {
 $i=5;
$numero=0;  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
       ->setCellValue('B'.$i,$numero );
 }
}